# iOS Today Extension Management

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

I'd like to improve the performance of an iOS Today Extension I'm building and my main problem is the memory management related to `UIView`.

I have an UIView variable already shown in the widget:

```
weak var backgroundView : BackgroundView!
```

After pressing a button I instance a new `BackgroundView`, add it to the subviews hierarchy on top of the previous `backgroundView` variable and replace it with the new view:

```
    let nextBackground = BackgroundView.instanceFromNibFor(roomType)
    nextBackground.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.insertSubview(nextBackground, aboveSubview: self.backgroundView)
    self.backgroundView = nextBackground
    nextBackground.removeFromSuperview()
```

The extension consumes 13,5 MB idle but everytime I add a new `BackgroundView` it adds 1,5 MB of memory usage. Shouldn't it remain stable if I'm replacing the previous `BackgroundView` with the new one? Also, is there a way to monitor which UIViews are the most memory consuming?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're calling `removeFromSuperview()` on the new one, not the old one.

Comment: Yes but that is because I assign the new one to the previously created backgroundView. I want to replace the old one with the new one.